# Edges of screen cut off in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, screen, monitor

I have a Visio 19" t.v that I am using as a high-def monitor. I am using a PCI graphics card (EVGA GeForce 8400 GS). I am using an HDMI cable to transmit the display. I have already checked and updated propriety drivers (got the NVIDIA drivers from the propriety driver option in the System Settings). The problem is: about half a centimeter is cut off of the top and bottom of the screen, a good centimeter is cut off both right and left sides. In addition to it being to "zoomed in" the quality of the image is not very good. Image doesn't look sharp or crisp at all. Colors are dull and nothing is overly vibrant, poor picture quality in general.
Here's the catch...this exact t.v monitor and the graphics card worked GREAT on Ubuntu 11.10, but ever since I upgraded to 12.04 the display has been crappy.
In Display under System Settings it shows the display as "unknown" and the resolution is set to the maximum (1280 X 720). Also, I went into my monitor's settings and ensured that the vertical and horizontal position/sizes were not increased or dis-positioned to create this "zoomed in" effect.
Any help is MUCH appreciated!
Thanks, Preston.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your nvidia settings configuration utility (IIRC nvidia-setting) and look for an overscan option. This sounds very much like overscan.

[image]

Comment: You may also need to see if Overscan/Underscan or HDMI-Scan settings of your TV are appropriate.

Comment: It was, just typed "nvidia" in the dash home search menu and it was under my monitor's display settings. Thank you tgm4883 and Takkat!