# Unity cropping external monitor: how do I fix it?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display, resolution

I I have a dual-screen setup with my laptop (1366x768) and an external monitor connected through HDMI (primary 1920x1080).

I don't know if this is cause by different aspect ratios (16:10 on laptop, 16:9 on external monitor) but Unity appears cropped approximately as shown in this picture:

[image]

If I use a lower resolution (1680x1050, 16:10) the desktop is correctly displayed, but those extra pixels could be handy.

So is this any limitation/bug on Unity? How can I make it display the desktop correctly at 1920x1080 pixels?

In case it could help, [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5595886/) of `xrandr` command.

Comment: for completeness' sake: do you have Unity's Launcher set to only be shown on your primary (laptop) monitor -- and *not* on the external monitor?

Comment: The launcher is shown on both screens.

Comment: ...which is what you want ( ...and what you wouldn't want to trade-in for an uncropped primary monitor) ?

Comment: Even if I make the launcher appear in only one screen the external one is still cropped (I can't see no window controls or scroolbar, when maximized).

Comment: Are you using NVIDIA ? if so, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/80324/hdmi-vga-connection-cuts-borders-of-screen-or-creates-blurry-text-unfocused-for and http://askubuntu.com/questions/125575/edges-of-screen-cut-off-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Yes I have a nVidia card (Optimus) with nouveau, so I can't use nVidia settings. I was able to fix this by changing my Samsung TV setup (Picture -> Screen Adjustement -> Picture Size: Screen Fit) as told on one of those links you provided. Please create an answer to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [HDMI/VGA connection cuts borders of screen or creates blurry text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80324/hdmi-vga-connection-cuts-borders-of-screen-or-creates-blurry-text-unfocused-for) (and also [Edges of screen cut off in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125575/edges-of-screen-cut-off-in-ubuntu-12-04)):

> NOTE (Comment made by User James -
>   https://askubuntu.com/users/39762/james): For some **Samsung** LCD TVs.
>   Using the TV Remote Control go to **Options** -> Picture Options and set
>   the Picture Option to "**Fit to Screen**".

Hope this helps.