# My screen is bigger than my TV, how can I change the size?

Tags: nvidia, resolution, screen, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu on a Mid-2010 Mac Mini with in-built Nvidia 320M graphics, it's connected to a 32" LCD TV via HDMI cable. The edges of the screen are 'cut off' somewhat, and changing the resolution doesn't seem to help. Can anyone help me change the size of the screen?

If it helps, the display is recognised as a 'JVC 7"' in the settings, it is most certainly NOT 7".

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/4358/how-do-i-fix-overscan-on-my-hdmi-hdtv or http://askubuntu.com/questions/125575/edges-of-screen-cut-off-in-ubuntu-12-04 -> search for "overscan" here to get even more results.

Answer (score 2):

Your TV probably believes that your computer is a set top box or something like that. And it does it by looking at the HDMI port label. If it's labelled as a cable box, DVD or similar, it requests an Over-/Underscanned image.

Make sure the HDMI port on the TV is set to "PC"

On my 47 inch LG TV, I set it at Menu->Option->Input label

Comment: Thank you. The answers I found before this suggested I go into the configuration of the OS, when all I had to do was this.